# How do I except specific ports when using a VPN?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, openvpn, windows-firewall

I'm using OpenVPN on Windows 10. I'd like to exclude traffic on certain ports (for example, SSH) from the VPN and instead use the underlying network. Can this be done?

On Linux, I'd imagine using `iptables` with `-p tcp --dport 22` to redirect to the underlying device instead of the VPN tunnel device to do this. What are my options on Windows?

The VPN has (so far) assigned me an IP in the `10.9.0.0/16` range. The underlying network gives me an IP in `10.13.0.0/16`, and most of my SSH traffic goes to `10.105.0.0/16` in the underlying network, or to Github (`nslookup` tells me that's `192.30.252.128`).

Comment: OpenVPNs client doesn't support this, some commercial VPN products do to my knowledge.

Comment: @Linef4ult so this must be handled by the VPN client? Nothing to be done on the OS side?

Comment: @muru -- Is the host you want to `ssh` to in the same LAN as the VPN client or a different one ?  Please add full details to your question

Comment: @dotvotdot could be either - I might want to SSH to Github or to a PC in the next room. Does it make a difference?

Comment: The problem leads to very complicated routing rules.  If you add two examples to your question I will try to answer those specifically.

Comment: @dotvotdot I'd prefer a general answer, but I have added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your home LAN is `10.13.0.0/16`, I presume your Home gateway is `10.13.0.1`
Your VPN subnet is `10.9.0.0/16`, I presume your VPN gateway is `10.9.0.1`
 then we can add these routing rules:

To route your SSH via the LAN gateway **not** the VPN

```
route add 10.105.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 10.13.0.1
```

To route GIT via your the LAN gateway **not** the VPN

```
route add 192.30.252.128 mask 255.255.255.255 10.13.0.1
```

Comment: So, this can only be done on the basis of the destination IP, but not based on the port?

Comment: As pointed out to you already -- `openvpn` does not filter **anything** on port numbers.  This is the **only** way you can achieve your result in Windows. [edit: that I know of]

Comment: But, maybe it's my Linux background confusing me, but, again, is the VPN client supposed to do this? (I asked the other commenter too, but no response).

Comment: `OpenVPN` client or server does not/can not and probably never will filter on ports, this is achieved in Linux with `iptables` ..I am not aware of a product solution like `iptables` with Windows.